# How do I update 1.3 billion rows in this table more efficiently?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, large-data

I have 1.3 billion rows in a PostgreSQL table `sku_comparison` that looks like this:

```
id1 (INTEGER) | id2 (INTEGER) | (10 SMALLINT columns) | length1 (SMALLINT)... |

... length2 (SMALLINT) | length_difference (SMALLINT)
```

The `id1` and `id2` columns are referenced in a table called `sku`, which contains about 300,000 rows, and have an associated `varchar(25)` value in each row from a column, `code`.

There is a btree index built on `id1` and `id2`, and a compound index of `id1` and `id2` in `sku_comparison`. There is a btree index on the `id` column of `sku`, as well.

My goal is to update the `length1` and `length2` columns with the lengths of the corresponding `code` column from the `sku` table. However, I ran the following code for over 20 hours, and it did not complete the update:

```
UPDATE sku_comparison SET length1=length(sku.code) FROM sku 
WHERE sku_comparison.id1=sku.id;
```

All of the data is stored on a single hard disk on a local computer, and the processor is fairly modern. Constructing this table, which required much more complicated string comparisons in Python, only took about 30 hours or so, so I am not sure why something like this would take as long.

edit: here are formatted table definitions:

```
                                     Table "public.sku"
   Column   |         Type          |                    Modifiers                     
------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer               | not null default nextval('sku_id_seq'::regclass)
 sku        | character varying(25) | 
 pattern    | character varying(25) | 
 pattern_an | character varying(25) | 
 firsttwo   | character(2)          | default '  '::bpchar
 reference  | character varying(25) | 
Indexes:
    "sku_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "sku_sku_idx" UNIQUE, btree (sku)
    "sku_firstwo_idx" btree (firsttwo)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "sku_comparison" CONSTRAINT "sku_comparison_id1_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id1) REFERENCES sku(id)
    TABLE "sku_comparison" CONSTRAINT "sku_comparison_id2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES sku(id)


            Table "public.sku_comparison"
          Column           |   Type   |        Modifiers        
---------------------------+----------+-------------------------
 id1                       | integer  | not null
 id2                       | integer  | not null
 consec_charmatch          | smallint | 
 consec_groupmatch         | smallint | 
 consec_fieldtypematch     | smallint | 
 consec_groupmatch_an      | smallint | 
 consec_fieldtypematch_an  | smallint | 
 general_charmatch         | smallint | 
 general_groupmatch        | smallint | 
 general_fieldtypematch    | smallint | 
 general_groupmatch_an     | smallint | 
 general_fieldtypematch_an | smallint | 
 length1                   | smallint | default 0
 length2                   | smallint | default 0
 length_difference         | smallint | default '-999'::integer
Indexes:
    "sku_comparison_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id1, id2)
    "ssd_id1_idx" btree (id1)
    "ssd_id2_idx" btree (id2)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "sku_comparison_id1_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id1) REFERENCES sku(id)
    "sku_comparison_id2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES sku(id)
```

Comment: Please explain your table definitions in (DDL) code, not in text.

Comment: Your update will touch *all* the rows in `sku_comparison_pkey`. Will the values *change* for all the rows?

Comment: Yes, all values are updated. I used  Python's psycopg2 to initially construct the table in batches, but in hindsight I forgot to include the lengths of the codes, which I want to use to alongside the other columns.

Comment: Try dropping all indexes/constraints from sku_comparison before running the update command, then recreate when complete. I do this when I need to do bulk updates, the performance improvement is huge.

Comment: Wouldn't it take longer since each update has to search the entire column, taking O(n^2) time instead of O(n * log(n))?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using an anonymous code block?

using pseudo code...

```
FOREACH 'SELECT ski.id, 
                sku.code, 
                length(sku.code) 
         FROM   sku 
         INTO   v_skuid, v_skucode, v_skulength'
DO 
 UPDATE sku_comparison 
 SET sku_comparison.length1 = v_skulength
 WHERE sku_comparison.id1=v_skuid;
END DO
END FOREACH
```

This would break the whole thing into smaller transactions and you will not be evaluating the length of sku.code every time.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluating the length of sku.code every time"?

Comment: Also, I just remembered that my data insertion was done in parallel with 10 threads. Can I do something similar with updates if the updated rows don't overlap?

Comment: @user1362215, what i meant by evaluating every time, is that your sku_comparison has multiple instances of the same sku.code and in your update stmt, you were evaluating the length at every row updated. But if you use a loop and evaluate the length outside the update stmt, you wouldn't be wasting the CPU cycles on the evaluating the length on every row.

Comment: @user1362215, I don't think you can kick off multithreaded update from the server, but you probably can rig it using client side code. for arguments sake lets say your sku.code starts with Alpha characters.  What i would do is encapsulate that logic with the looping inside a function/stored procedure and add an input parameter to hold 1st letter of sku.code. then in the loop i'd add the where clause WHERE sku.code ilike p_param1 || '%'. So this would execute for that subset of rows. Now in your client code you can execute the function 26 times one for each letter of alphabet. HTH

Comment: Oh, so it evaluates length(sku.code) 300,000 times instead of 1.3 billion times?

Comment: @user1362215, yes putting the length(sku.code) outside the update stmt will result in it being evaluated on 300,000 and not the 1.3 billion times if that was in the Update Stmt.